# Merge data from two sheets into correct row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets, with data similar to this:

```
SHEET 1:
     A     B     C
1    Josh  30    Austin
2    Sam   28    SF
3    Mary  35    Chicago

SHEET 2:
     A     B
1    Josh  Car
2    Mary  Truck
3    Sam   Van
```

What I'm attempting to do is merge the two based on Column A.  For example, the outcome would be:

```
     A     B     C       D
1    Josh  30    Austin  Car
2    Sam   28    SF      Van
3    Mary  35    Chicago Truck
```

I've tried digging through the Excel support on Microsoft's site, but I'm not getting anywhere.  Originally I thought it would have something to do with the Data > Consolidate feature, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Use a simple VLOOKUP function if all the names will only appear once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that your names are unique in Sheet2,
On Sheet1 Cell D1 enter:

```
=Vlookup(a1,Sheet2!a:b,2,0)
```

And drag it until the end of your data.